# About ListChange Event Behaviour

Tags: c#, wpf, events, data-binding, bindinglist

I have List name `OrderList` which contain object of `Order` type and `Order` Contain another List `OrderDetailList` of OrderDetail type now `OrderList` subscribe to `ListChange` event and it works fine as long as i change `Order` property but if i change `OrderdetailList` which eventually property of `Order` class event is not fairing, did it has to work like that or am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Sorry can't provide that ( as company policy ) just consider list inside list if inside list change the other list's change event doesn't fire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really, really want the same event firing for both lists attach the handler to both of them. What your seeing is the expected behavior.